# How to install pip for python 3.8 other then with "get-pip.py"?

Tags: python, pip

I am unable to install pip for python on my computer (Windows 8). I tried to do: "pip install pandas" through cmd and that's when I got message:" 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " I tried to fix the problem by adding suitable PATH to environment variables but it seemed that it is not the problem since I already had proper PATH. Then I checked my Scripts folder but it is empty. I tried reinstalling Python, and also tried executing the get-pip.py file but was not able to install it. Is there anybody with similar experience that could help me? I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Have you tried `py -m pip install pandas`?

Comment: I have and it says: "No module named pip". 
It is pretty odd I have empty Scripts folder, with no pip.exe or any other file, it might be something to do with that, but I don't know what could be causing Scripts to be empty :(